# How to get screenshot for each soft assert failure with AssertJ SoftAssertions

Tags: java, testng, assertion, assertj, assertthat

I want to achieve below: -

```
CustomSoftAssertJ softly = new CustomSoftAssertJ();
softly.assertThat(actual).isEqualTo(expected); // get screen shot on failure
softly.assertThat(actual).isEqualTo(expected); // get screen shot on failure
softly.assertThat(actual).isEqualTo(expected); // get screen shot on failure
softly.assertThat(actual).isEqualTo(expected); // get screen shot on failure
softly.assertAll();
```

And I am trying below and it is not working: -

```
public class CustomSoftAssertJ extends AbstractSoftAssertions {
    @Override
    public void onAssertionErrorCollected(AssertionError assertionError) {
        super.onAssertionErrorCollected(assertionError);
        ExtentReport.getTest().fail(assertionError.getLocalizedMessage(),
                MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromBase64String(ScreenshotUtils.getBase64Image()).build());
    }
}
```

I saw the original documentation from AssertJ, However I could not get it.
Could someone help me out here with simple example?